# Symfony2 KnpMenuBundle automatically load?

Tags: symfony, bundle

In symfony2, I have a CMS bundle that requires that KnpMenuBundle be loaded. Is there a way to have the CMS bundle automatically load the menu bundle?

Or do I need to always but the menu bundle into AppKernel manually when I install the CMS bundle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting it in appKernal is doing exactly what you want. Learn about lazy loading and dependency injection. In order to utilize a bundle, it needs to be in appKernal